# Android Google Map How to Parse alternate route's distance

Tags: android, google-maps

I will be posting all of my codes here and a sample output of my project.  I have set the alternative to yes to display the alternate routes but problem is, how do I parse all the distance from all routes? It only gets the distance of the main route but not the alternate routes. How do I change my Parse java class to get all the directions in alternate routes and display it?

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,DirectionFinderListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

/**************************************************************/
   // private GoogleMap mMap;

    private ImageButton btnFindPath;
    private AutoCompleteTextView etOrigin;
    private AutoCompleteTextView etDestination;
    private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "MY API KEY HERE";

//FOR COLLAPSING TOOLBAR
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

    /**************************************************************************************************************/
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    GoogleMap mMap;

    MapView mapView;
    View Myview;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third_fragment, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
/********************************************************************/
        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) Myview.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

        /****************************************************************************************/

        btnFindPath = (ImageButton) Myview.findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
        etOrigin = (AutoCompleteTextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
        etDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
        btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });

        etOrigin.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
        etOrigin.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        etDestination.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
        etDestination.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return Myview;
    }

    //**********For changing colors in the directions************************************************************/


    /**************************************************************************************************************/

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        goToLocationZoom(9.3068, 123.3054, 15);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        LatLngBounds Dumaguete = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(9.267, 123.264), new LatLng(9.33, 123.311));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(Dumaguete);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Dumaguete.getCenter(), 15));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    private void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, int zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");

    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
        String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
        if (origin.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (destination.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait.",
                "Finding direction..!", true);

        if (originMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (destinationMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (polylinePaths != null) {
            for (Polyline polyline : polylinePaths) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
        }
    }


        @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Directions found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (final Route route : routes) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));

            ((TextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);   //For Distance


            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));

            destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));



            /******************For Changing color ********************************************************/
            mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                    // Flip the values of the red, green and blue components of the polyline's color.
                    polyline.setColor(polyline.getColor() ^ 0x00ffffff);
                      //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        /*************************************************************************************************/

        Random rnd = new Random();

           int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(257), rnd.nextInt(258));

        /**/
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).color(color).width(15).clickable(true);




            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));


            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

        }


    }



    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&types=establishment&strictbounds&location=9.30684,123.305447&radius=2000");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return String.valueOf(resultList.get(index));
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}//End of CLass ThirdFragment.java
```

This is my Data Parsing and how do I change it to also get the distance of the alternate routes?

DirectionFInder.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




public class DirectionFinder {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyC1E8NU2jjoQF7dN37bIOz_1fy0fe98YhI";
    private DirectionFinderListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;




    public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, String destination) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();
        new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl());
    }

    private String createUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");
        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "utf-8");


        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination +"&alternatives=true" +"&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;


        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");



            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng(
                    lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d
            ));
        }

        return decoded;
    }
}
```

[This is the screenshot of the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rctI.png) 
The dark green color is the main route and the pink and blue are the alternate routes. How can I get the distance of the pink and blue as well? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are already looping through all of the routes, so storing the distance for each route should be simple. This line of code is where you get the distance for each route:

```
route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));'
```

If you create an array, you can store the value of each route during each iteration of the loop. Let's say you have an array called routeDistances[]. You could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
        Route route = new Route();

        JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
        JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
        JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
        JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

        routeDistances[i] = jsonDistance.getInt("value"); // add this line

        route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
        route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
        route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
        route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
        route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

        routes.add(route);
    }
```

The line of code will allow you to store the distance for each route. You can then get the distance using the array. For example routeDistances[0] will have the distance for the first route, routeDistances[1] will have the distance for the next route etc.

Comment: Thank you sir @Stephen... on my codes, it seems that when I click all all the given routes, it will display only the main route by google map. example, I click on route 1, displays main route, click route 2, displays main route, click route 3, displays main route.... What I need to do is when I click on routes 2 and 3, it will display it's respective route values. Do you know how to do it? I badly need help sir.