# Google maps android store List of Routes in a List

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to store the "list of routes" inside a list? How to do it please? I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer which adds the route to the ArrayList. This way you can add all routes to an ArrayList - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007360/1649353

Comment: Thank you, I already have that. However, since I have to show the alternative routes, I also have to get the distance of each alternative route if it is present. My professor suggested that how about storing that list of routes inside a list. Is it possible sir @Ambuj Kathotiya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15423611/1649353 Like this you need to create an Object where you have to define list for one route,then add it to an arrayList of that object to store all the routes.

Comment: Thank you. Sir, If I may, Do you have any idea on this question though? I badly need answers. @Ambuj Kathotiya[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520564/android-google-map-how-to-parse-alternate-routes-distance]